# Connect PowerBI to Google Big Query through a proxy server (corporate network)

Tags: proxy, google-bigquery, odbc, powerbi

We are trying to make a connection from PowerBI Desktop, to the Google Big Query Database. Upon starting the app and immediately after trying to make the connection to the Google Data Source, we get the error below:

Unable to Connect
We encountered an error.

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error interacting with REST API: Couldn't resolve host name
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error interacting with REST 
API: Couldn't resolve host name"
```

I suppose that it has something to do with the proxy used inside our corporate environment but i haven't found anything so far on what urls/ports should be opened in order for this connection to work.

Please do keep in mind that this is a new business need and it is not something that worked and stopped working.